# JNI4Net on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, c#, mono, java-native-interface, jni4net

Is is possible to use JNI4Net on linux ubuntu. I see not specific download seciton for linux.
I have found this [example](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html) with use of JNI with out third party library JNI4Net.

I would like to simplify my life with this library.

I am trying to expose .net libraries to java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono/Linux is not yet supported in jni4net. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Only Windows 32 and 64 bits are supported for now.